# What is the generic term for technologies like AWS Athena (Presto) and GCP BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, presto, amazon-athena

From a user perspective, Athena and BigQuery both accept a sql-like query, they both query files stored on disk (without needing to have set up a relational database), and they both return results (usually very quickly). Do such technologies have a name? i.e. is there a generic term for technologies like AWS Athena and GCP BigQuery?

Comment: MPP (Massively Parallel Processing) Data warehouse

Answer (score 1):

They are both distributed SQL Query Engines for big [in-place] data. Athena is based on [Presto](http://prestodb.github.io/), which declares itself to be a *Distributed SQL Query Engine for Big Data*.

[Apache Drill](https://drill.apache.org/) was based on the original BigQuery design and defines itself as a *Schema-free SQL Query Engine for Hadoop, NoSQL and Cloud Storage*

The three things that define them are the possibility of running SQL, their distributed nature so they can operate at scale for interactive queries, and the power to query data without having to ingest it first.

Note in the case of BigQuery, initially the data would need to be ingested and it is still the preferred way of working, even if querying data directly from GCS has been available for a number of years. Athena only works with external tables.

Answer (score 0):

Google BigQuery is a serverless data warehouse that supports super-fast SQL queries for analyze data in parallel. Amazon Athena is a serverless interactive query service that allows you to conveniently analyze data stored in Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3) by using basic SQL in parallel.

Both technologies could be considered as **[MPP](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/MPP-massively-parallel-processing)** (massively parallel processing) systems as both technologies process data analytics in parallel.